# xcbuild didn't run tests even though it can be run from XCode

Tags: ios, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am trying to do the tests form the terminal and `xcpretty` the output. Here is the command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace bimb-authenticate-ios.xcworkspace -scheme bimb-authenticate-ios-afx -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro,OS=16.4' -enableCodeCoverage YES -derivedDataPath Build/ clean build test | xcpretty -c "--report" "html" "--output" "../Project_report.html"
```

However, the tests are never run. The simulator is not even run. Here's the last items of the `xcbuild` logs:

```
2024-03-27 21:42:37.151 xcodebuild[84540:2237180] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 264.553 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2024-03-27 21:42:37.152 xcodebuild[84540:2237180] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.001 sec, +0.001 sec -- start
2024-03-27 21:42:37.152 xcodebuild[84540:2237180] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 264.554 sec, +264.553 sec -- end
▸ Test Succeeded
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your scheme have the tests?

Comment: Yes it has the tests. I can run the tests with the scheme on XCode. But it failed with xcbuild.

Comment: Can you test creating a scheme only for tests?

Comment: @ReinierMelian you know what? it worked when I created a new scheme. weird.

Comment: Well in the current project I am working on we use a scheme only for tests and it works

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'll do just that. I'll just use this scheme for the CI/CD. Although it is kind of odd since the scheme is exactly the same. To my knowledge anyway.